# Using .PEM file from AWS, asking for passphrase

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, mac-osx

I am using macOS Sierra and have been using AWS for a few months now and I have always connected using

```
ssh -i file.pem ec2-user@myserver.com
```

But today when I try connect I am being asked for the passphrase to the pem file.

```
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: 'key.pem'
Enter passphrase for key 'key.pem':
```

I haven't set a passphrase and now cannot connect to our servers

Any advice?

**Note**: I created the key on the AWS portal. Then downloaded it.

Comment: I created the key on the AWS portal. Then downloaded it.

Comment: @Mugurel what do you mean by "*an actual new line*"? `\n` is not new line for you?

Comment: Did you encrypt it using `ssh-keygen`?

Comment: Just as a note, and for reference in the future: You should keep private keys private, and therefore generate these sort of keys only machines you control, i.e. your notebook / workstation, **by any means not in the cloud.**

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue similar to this. I'd copied a private key from a .pem file. When I pasted it into another .pem file I noticed a `%` at the end of `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, like this `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----%`. When I tried to connect with it to a private server I was asked for a passphrase. I went back and removed the `%` and it worked fine.

Comment: Seconded, If your private key string is wrong by even a single character or with faulty newlines, it'll be silently rejected and you'll be prompted for the pem file's password.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. if you are copying from one editor into another, Ensure you are copying from :
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
till
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

This is most definitely an issue with the pem key file not getting copied fully.

Answer (score 1):

while copying the file we should not select ctrl+A as rather we need to copy it manually from begin to end of the file without missing any character but also should not include any extra space after the end of the line.

it worked after that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Given it is asking passphrase for key.pem, whereas you have file.pem in command-line, either there is something wrong with your pem file or the command-line.

Did you copy/pasted this cmd-line, if yes then type manually. Atleast on windows, the minus character can sometimes be a weird character when copied from Outlook email, etc. and gives strange errors.

2nd, validate your file.pem. See its file-size and last modification date and type puttygen file.pem -L .. to do basic sanity check if this file is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Open your PEM file and make sure it doesn't have any white space or empty lines. Specifically make sure each line starts with a character and not a `space`.

I had this issue and found that when I copy/pasted the contents of the file, it put some white space at the beginning of each line. When I removed the white space, it fixed the `Enter passphrase for key 'key.pem':` issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. For me, the solution was to delete extra text from my secret key's .pem file. For example, initially the file looked like this...

```
12:ac:f2:10:ac:34:3a:da:12:df:ca:34:3a:22:aa:21:34:b3:52:4d -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<a really long string (i.e. the private key)
<10-20 more lines>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----   MyKeyPair3
```

I had to delete that first string (by the way, for privacy, I changed the value from what was actually in my secret key).
I also had to delete the name of my key (MyKeyPair3) from the end of the file.
Finally, there was an empty line at the end of the file. I needed to delete this line as well.
The resulting file that caused no errors looks like this...

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    <a really long string (i.e. the private key)
    <10-20 more lines>
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'
```

I hope this is helpful to others with the same issue.
Cheers!